# -Wstringop-overflow warning when length allocated to destination string is equal to source

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, compiler-warnings, strncpy

I am using GCC 10.2.0 with C++17, and I get the following error:

```
ioapi.c: In function ‘file_build_ioposix’:
ioapi.c:125:5: warning: ‘strncpy’ specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  125 |     strncpy(ioposix->filename, filename, ioposix->filenameLength);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ioapi.c:123:31: note: length computed here
  123 |     ioposix->filenameLength = strlen(filename) + 1;
```

And this is my code:

```
static voidpf file_build_ioposix(FILE *file, const char *filename)
{
    FILE_IOPOSIX *ioposix = NULL;
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ioposix = (FILE_IOPOSIX*)malloc(sizeof(FILE_IOPOSIX));
    ioposix->file = file;
    ioposix->filenameLength = strlen(filename) + 1;
    ioposix->filename = (char*)malloc(ioposix->filenameLength * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(ioposix->filename, filename, ioposix->filenameLength);
    return (voidpf)ioposix;
}
```

Problem here is this should be considered okay, since destination is set to source length + 1, but it still provides an error.

Tried checking for failed malloc, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: Since you just have allocated the exact amount of space for the string, there is no need to use a function that performs additional checks (and `strncpy` is to be avoided in general because of its misleading name and counterintuitive semantics). Use `strcpy` or `memcpy`. NB, `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is kind of a false positive.
The warning tries to catch cases such as `strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src) + 1)` where the destination buffer is written to, past its end.

> ```cpp
> ioposix->filenameLength = strlen(filename) + 1;
> ioposix->filename = (char*)malloc(ioposix->filenameLength * sizeof(char));
> strncpy(ioposix->filename, filename, ioposix->filenameLength);
> ```

In this particular case, the size of the destination buffer is equal to the size of the source buffer, since the destination buffer was allocated with `malloc` to have exactly the right size.
`strncpy` is safe as used, and the warning is a false positive.

However, `strncpy` is also pointless because this could have been written as:

```cpp
ioposix->filenameLength = strlen(filename) + 1;
ioposix->filename = (char*)malloc(ioposix->filenameLength); // sizeof(char) == 1
memcpy(ioposix->filename, filename, ioposix->filenameLength);
```

Or using [`memdup`](https://manpages.org/memdup/3) (from POSIX, or written yourself for convenience)

```cpp
ioposix->filenameLength = strlen(filename) + 1;
ioposix->filename = (char*)memdup(filename, ioposix->filenameLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

[strncpy(dest, src, count)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) copies characters from `src` until it encounters `'\0'` or copies `count` symbols, whichever comes first. The warning reflects that allocating `count` bytes and passing the same `count` to `strncpy()` is generally dangerous: you may end up with a non-null-terminated string. You won't in this specific case since `src[count-1]` is guaranteed to be `'\0'` but seemingly warning system misses that.

Notice that a "warning" isn't an "error" and *may* be issued for a perfectly correct code.